# Remove delivered notification from tray without opening app

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is Voip application written in ReactNative (Android and IOS)
The calling process is custom made by sending to user push notifications every x seconds.

*Delivering the notification with FCM.*

On android, If I deliver multiple notifications with the same ID, it will deliver multiple times, but display only once on **notification try**.

On IOS I would like to accomplish the same result.

Is there a way or to deliver a few notifications and make them display once at **Notification tray**?

Or

**How remove notifications from the tray without opening the app?**

*I can't use CallKit since I'm using custom UI for out and in calls.*

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, how did you made the VOIP application for Android and IOS? Especially which library or implementation did you used for Android?

Comment: @TimDirks Hi, I used Twillio

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't set up your own SIP server and implemented Pushkit (IOS) or PJSIP module (IOS & Android) :https://github.com/Carusto/react-native-pjsip-app?

Comment: Just a lot of overhead...

Comment: What do you suggest when I want to use my own SIP server? I already implemented the Pushkit module for IOS, but i'm looking now for a android solution for VoiP notifications to make calls.

Comment: PushKit a minor step. Has not much to do with actual Voip calls, I would recommend you to give it a try making your own server, and if you fail to move to a service like Twilio, they wrap all logic up very nicely, but they are quite expensive